# Undefined reference to libspatialindex functions in C++

Tags: c++, spatial-index

I'm just getting started with libspatialindex. I ran through the [instructions to install](http://libspatialindex.github.io/install.html) and it installed ok on ubuntu with the following commands (except I couldn't find autogen.sh which it mentions).

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

then I made a very simple program to test it as follows (based on [this](https://github.com/libspatialindex/libspatialindex/wiki/Simple-Tutorial))

```
#include <spatialindex/capi/sidx_api.h>
using namespace SpatialIndex;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* pszVersion = SIDX_Version();
}
```

and compile as follows:

```
g++ -lspatialindex spatial.cpp -o spatial
```

and it gives me the error:

```
/tmp/ccACK3p4.o: In function `main':
spatial.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `SIDX_Version'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried many different things such as using cmake instead and installing it a different folder but no luck. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Added the namespace SpatialIndex above and I also tried the following, but still not luck:

```
g++ -c -o spatial.o spatial.cpp
g++ -o spatial spatial.o -lspatialindex -lm
```

Comment: Did you include the spatialindex namespace?

Comment: The error says that the linker dont find the corresponding code. Please try changing the order :
g++ spatial.cpp -lspatialindex  -o spatial
I'm not very confident  with single line compiling&link. I always use two pass: first compile and then link objects with required libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @itachi, I tried adding the namespace SpatialIndex (I edited the question above to show this too) but still no luck. How can I tell what namespace SIDX_Version is in? It's not clear from the docs http://libspatialindex.github.io/doxygen/sidx__api_8h.html

Comment: @MelVisoMartinez, I tried it the other way around and separating the compiling&link (as shown in the edit to question I did) but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about linking phase. The library is correctly found because the compiler dont throws alert(s) of that kind of situation (I just made a test now). 
do a

```
> nm libspatialindex |grep SIDX_Version
```

for checking the symbol existence in the library you are using. May be libspatialindex_c instead?

Comment: Thanks, I tried `gcc -g spatial.c -o spatial -lspatialindex` but it gave me the error `In file included from /usr/local/include/spatialindex/SpatialIndex.h:30:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/spatialindex/capi/sidx_config.h:56,
                 from /usr/local/include/spatialindex/capi/sidx_api.h:34,
                 from spatial.c:1:
/usr/local/include/spatialindex/tools/Tools.h:59:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory`

Comment: I am really confused... The example you referred is typical c and is what "capi" suggest, but these includes are ¡using classes!. I'm sorry I will delete my reponse later. Plese do a nm over the library for checking if  the missing symbol is here and let me know if it's inside or not.

Comment: @Patrick64 Do you have some like libspatialindex_c? I have seen an example that seems to link against libspatialindex_c instead of libspatialindex.

Comment: Yes there is a libspatialindex_c.a file in /usr/local/lib folder, `gcc -g spatial.c -lspatialindex_c -o spatial` does the same as before.

Comment: Ok, but I was wrong before and you need to use your g++ compilation (with cpp source file) but linking against this other lib. :)

Comment: If this fails due to missing symbols, include both libraries with -lspatialindex_c and -lspatialindex (in this order).
I must left for rest. I hope this helps.

Comment: You've cracked it, thanks so much. I did `g++ spatial.cpp -lspatialindex_c -lspatialindex -L/usr/local/lib -o spatial` and it works! I also needed to run `sudo ldconfig` before running the program.

Comment: @Patrick64 - That you needed to run sudo ldconfig sounds like a bug in the install. I don't know what libspatialindex is, but this happens a lot with "free" software.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `libspatialindex` install target is `/usr/local`. You didn't override that in your invocation of `./configure`, so that's where `make install` will install things.

The compiler knows to look for include files in `/usr/local/include`, so compilation isn't a problem. It however does not know to look for libraries in `usr/local/lib`. A simple fix is to add that to your link step:

```
g++ -o spatial spatial.o -lspatialindex -lm -L/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Same problem I'm afraid, although that folder does contain `libspatialindex.a` and similar files so maybe it helps to get closer to the solution.